# R memory error (RStudio) do while command process

Tags: r, memory

I have a Windows 8.1 / 64bit / SSD 240Gb / 12Gb RAM.
I'm just running Rstudio but I can't complete a task as it gives me the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.1 Gb`. I noticed that while running R it, windows have between 5/6 Gb of RAM left. what could it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: cannot allocate vector of size 57.8 Gb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201959/error-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-57-8-gb)

Comment: But because even having RAM available, R can't use it?

Comment: R can allocate more memory if it's available. Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395229/increasing-or-decreasing-the-memory-available-to-r-processes

Comment: I tried to allocate 11.5 GB, but even so, R returns saying it is impossible to allocate a vector with 28.8 GB. It seems to me that R to execute the command, it generates a 28 GB temporary file and it can't finish!!!

Comment: I tried using `memory.limit()` as suggested, but even allocating about 11.5GB /12GB, R generates would need 28.8GB to complete the process. I don't know why it generates such a large data.frame.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the 32-bit version of R?